# retrieve id and url separately when rewriting with id and clean url

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am trying to get my url to look something like:

mysite.com/news/25-my-first-article

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)$ article-detail.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
```

and my href:

```
<li><a href="news/{$id}-{$slug}">{$title} <i class="icon arrow_right"></i></a></li>
```

This works correctly as far as I can see. If I click on a link the url looks how I want it to. The issue I am having is that I cannot get the id and slug into separate values.

If I echo out:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

then instead of just getting an id like "7" or "25" or whatever, I get 25-my-first-article

I just want the actual id value so I can then look it up in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the two values into separate groups:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)$ article-detail.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [NC,L]
```

Alternatively, you can just ignore the second part:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z-0-9-]+$ article-detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, I would use (this takes all the numbers in front and ignores the rest):

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+).*$ article-detail.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @user8463989 if so, please consider upvoting the answer and/or  marking it as accepted. Also, make sure to look at the added examples.

Answer (score -1):

Use follow code

`<?php $data=$_GET['id'];$temp=explode("-",$data);echo $temp[0];// you get Id ?>`

Comment: This code is formatted badly and works around the problem instead of solving it. -1.